# SSL on Tomcat 7 on Azure VM

Tags: java, tomcat, azure, ssl

I tried to configure SSL certificate for *Tomcat 7(7.0.61)* which I installed on Azure Windows VM.

Https does not work and there are no errors in Tomcat logs. I use Digicert certificate which gave me .jks keystore file. VM has its own DNS: `myVm.cloudapp.net` I registered my own domain `NNN.today` at `one.com` and make redirection from `NNN.today` to `myVm.cloudapp.net`.

When created certificate I used NNN.today. I configured endpoints for my VM (http for port 80 and SSL for port 443). APR listener is commented out in server.xml.
Here is my server.xml config:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8443" 
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
    enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" 
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server" 
    keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/app_farewell_today.jks" keystorePass="my_password" keystoreType="JKS"
    truststoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/app_farewell_today.jks" truststorePass="my_password" truststoreType="JKS"/>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the VM firewall configured to listen to this ports? Also, on the public endpoints you configured, did you map to the correct internal port? e.g. 8080 to 443?

Comment: good points. It looks like the problem is there...

Answer (score 1):

The VM's firewall should be configured to listen to this ports as well and the public endpoint configuration should map to the proper internal ports as well.